# Sails- relationship mapping

Tags: sails.js

I've 2 sails model

1) student

```
id - pk
name
revision
```

2) studentDetails

```
id
student_id -> fk
student_reviosion
```

Whenever student gets updated, revision is automatically increment by 1. How I can make sure that revision and student_revision should be sync in both table? Is there any way to define sails_model like that?
I know this can be achieve through lifecycble callback and would like to know if anything that we can directly achieve by defining some relation in sails models itself.

Answer (score 2):

You should choose just one of these tables to store the data in. Since you are creating a relation, you will be able to access the data when you need it.  For example if you keep revision in student, when you look up student details, you can do something like `let studentDetails = await StudentDetails.find({id: id}).populate('student')` [I am naming the foreign key to 'student' because it will make more sense when you populate it like this].
Then you can access all the information from the associated student record, like `studentDetails.student.revision`

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-one